# Mute output but still get audio to stereo mix?

Tags: audio

I'm using Airfoil in conjunction with stereo mix to broadcast my laptops audio to a raspberry pi running shairport, only problem is that the audio is still being played through my laptop speakers.

SO basically I'm looking for a way to somehow mute the local sound while still getting the audio to the stereo mix, is this possible? Hopefully I can do this with just software - also I really dont want to have to buy a Virtual Audio Cable license if possible.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hunted and hunted for a very long time but in the end couldn't find anything appropriate. Bit the bullet and got a license for Virtual Audio Cable - which does exactly what I wanted it to.